# Teradata Multiplying percentages in an Aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregate, teradata, multiplication

I am trying to do an agregate multiplication.  I'll use a baseball example.

Sample Table

```
team  player     battingavg  1-battingavg = nohitavg
1       A       0.123         0.877
1       B       0.144         0.856
1       C       0.210         0.790
2       E       0.142         0.858
2       F       0.231         0.769
2       G       0.125         0.875
```

I want to aggregate multiply to get the overall probability of having at no hits.

For team 1 =    (0.877) * (0.856) * (0.790) = probability of have no hits
For team 2 =    (0.858) * (0.769) * (0.875) = probability of have no hits

1 - probability of no hits = probability of at least 1 hit.

```
SELECT team
     , SOMEFUNCTION(nohitavg) as probofnohit 
FROM table 
GROUP BY team
```

Desired output

```
team  probofnohit
1        0.593
2        0.577
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically a **PRODUCT(nohitavg)** is the same as **EXP(SUM(LN(nohitavg)))**, but be careful this is based on FLOAD arithmetic (15 digits precision), you might add a cast NUMBER (38 digits) in TD14:

```
EXP(SUM(CAST(LN(nohitavg) AS NUMBER))))
```